# C# Generics limit to set of models (without a relating base-class)

Tags: c#, generics

Can't figure out what to google to figure this one out, but am hoping there is a way to simplify this. I have a set of entities that I am using that do not extend a base class(Level1, Level2, etc).  Level1 is the root, Level2 is the second tier and has a reference to Level1,etc. I have grossly simplified the example below, but have a lot of "repeated", templated, code and am searching for a way to simplify it.

I have a set of entities that are "Org" like, all I care about is `ID`, `Name`, and `Parent`.  I have a `OrgBO` class that wraps them that has a `BuildFrom` method per entity type.

```
//OrgBO class
public void BuildFrom(Level1 entity){
    this.ID = entity.Level1ID;
    this.Type = OrgTypes.Level1;
    this.Name = entity.Name;
    this.Parent = null;
}
public void BuildFrom(Level2 entity){
    this.ID = entity.Level2ID;
    this.Type = OrgTypes.Level2;
    this.Name = entity.Name;
    this.Parent = new OrgBO(entity.Level1);
}
```

I have created a constructor per type:

```
public OrgBO(Client entity){
    BuildFrom(entity);
}
public OrgBO(Region entity) {
    BuildFrom(entity);
}
```

But I'm repeating myself, am I missing a `generic` way of abstracting this?  Somehow have one constructor that calls `BuildFrom<T>` and somehow constraint it to a list of class types?

```
//not sure how to limit to my types..
public OrgBO<T>(T entity) {
    BuildFrom<T>(entity);
}
```

---

Hoping this isn't an early morning brain fart..  Extra info (in case peeps care).

```
 public enum OrgTypes { 
    Level1 = 1, 
    Level2 = 2, 
    Level3 = 3, 
    Level4 = 4 
};
```

Comment: Probably better suited at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It sounds like you might need an interface here, although honestly I don't see what's stopping you from making an "Org" base class?

Comment: I contemplated making this some type of interface and an abstract impl for OrgBO, then having a factory to find the right one and build it, but that seemed like some overdesign...

Comment: I wish there was a "migrate to chat" button... but they are database Entity Framework models... Basically are hard coded tables Level1 is the root, Level2 keys to Level1, etc.)

Comment: @Ic. you are suggesting editing my EF model and adding a base class ?  I tried doing that via the model explorer but ran into issues.. you have any blogs/examples?

Comment: It is unclear to me why your classes `Level1, Level2` are using different field names `Level1ID, Level2ID` for the same content (the id of the level) instead of implementing the same fields `Level1 l1 = new Level1(){ Id=345};` and the same for Level2 `Level2 l2 = new Level2(){ Id=864};`  You could create new methods `getLevelId()` and `getOrgType()` and `getParent()` but without knowing more about the Level classes it is difficult to recommend anything.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree its a set of database tables that I can not change.  They evolved over time... and I am just adapting to them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I pulled it off... thanks @IC. for pushing me in the right direction

```
public OrgBO(IOrgBase entity){
        PopulateFrom(entity);
}

public void PopulateFrom(IOrgBase entity){
        this.ID = entity.GetID();
        this.Type =  entity.GetEntityType();
        this.Name = entity.GetName();
        if (entity.GetParent() !=null)
        {
            this.Parent = new OrgBO(entity.GetParent());
        }
    }
```

--- Entity framework extension class...

```
namespace Unboxed.Models
{
  public interface IOrgBase{
    string GetName();
    int GetID();
    IOrgBase GetParent();
    string GetEntityType();
   }   

  [MetadataType(typeof(Level1_Meta))]
  public partial class Level1 : IOrgBase{

      #region IOrgBase impl
      public string GetName()
      {
        return Level1Name;
      }
      ....
      #endregion IOrgBase impl

      ...

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your level classes inherit from a common base class, make them inherit from a common interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    OrgTypes Type { get; } // Only getter, classes must know their own type.
    string Name { get; set; }
    IEntity Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can declare the Org type like this:

```
public class OrgBO<TEntity, TParent> : IEntity
    where TEntity : IEntity // Generic type constraints
    where TParent : IEntity
{
    private TEntity _entity;

    public OrgBO(TEntity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
        if (entity.Type == OrgTypes.Level1) {
            this.ParentBO = null;
        } else {
            this.ParentBO = new OrgBO<TParent>(entity.Parent);
        }
    }

    public int ID { get { return _entity.ID; } set{ _entity.ID = value; } }
    public OrgTypes Type { get { return _entity.Type; } }
    public string Name { get { return _entity.Name; } set{ _entity.Name = value; } }

    // Implement explicitly in order to hide it if not accesses through interface.
    IEntity IEntity.Parent {
        get { return _entity.Parent; }
        set{ _entity.Parent = value; }
    }

    public OrgBO<TParent> ParentBO { get; private set; }
}
```

A level class could look like this:

```
public class Level2 : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public OrgTypes Type { get { return OrgTypes.Level2; } }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEntity Parent { get; set; }

    public Level1 Level1Parent {
        get { return (Level1)Parent; }
        set { Parent = value; }
    }
}
```

Use a dummy `TParent` for Level1 objects like `new OrgBO<Level1, object>(level1Object)`. Of course you can also copy the entity values into the OrgBO objects instead of wrapping the entity object, if it better fits your needs.

Also `OrgBO` needs not necessarily to implement `IEntity`, but it makes sense because of the similarity. If it does not, the `Parent` property in `OrgBO` can be dropped.